# verifying prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

how one can show that weather $(x^2+y^2-1)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ or not?

what about $(x^2-y^2-1)$ ?

is it easier to show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is an integral domain ?

Comment: Using Eisenstein's Criterion, $x^2+y^2-1$ is an irreducible element of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]=\big(\mathbb{C}[y]\big)[x]$.  Since $\mathbb{C}$ is a unique factorization domain, so are $\mathbb{C}[y]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.  Thus, $x^2+y^2-1$ is a prime element of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: A user once said the Law of Conservation of Difficulty implies that proving that $\left\langle x^2+y^2-1\right\rangle$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is just as difficult as proving that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\left\langle x^2+y^2-1\right\rangle$ is an integral domain.  This is because the two statements are essentially the same thing.